# Link to new activity from IntentIntegrator

Tags: android, zxing

Our project consists of making an app that handles group payments. 
You can join a group by scanning a QRCode containing the id of the group you want to join. 
We have made an activity "AddOrJoinActivity" in which you can either Create or Join a group (By scanning the QR-Code). 
I have made a new Activity containing my CustomScanner which works.
The problem however is the following. 
I call the Customscanner from within the "AddOrJoinActivity" but once the code is scanned I want the program to open the activity "Groupdetails" containing all the details of the group he/she just joined.

I tried the following:
In "AddOrJoinActivity"

```
IntentIntegrator ii = new IntentIntegrator(this)
ii.setCaptureActivity(CustomScanner.class).initiateScan();
```

In "CustomScanner"

```
barcodeView =(CompoundBarcodeView)findViewById(R.id.customViewBarcode);
capture = new CaptureManager(this,barcodeView);
capture.initializeFromIntent(getIntent(),savedInstanceState);
capture.decode();
```

I tried making a new intent in Customscanner containing the GroupsDetailActivity and using that in the capture.initializeFromIntent() but that didn't work.

How can i start the groupdetailsactivity from the CustomScanner ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this tutorial?
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162

In your case, after scanning, in your code of `AddOrJoin`, the method `onActivityResult` will automatically execute. In that method, you'll retrieve your scanning results and can you do you magic in the database.

Start after the magic a new Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

That's my opinion.

Comment: Perfect! I did just start the new activity from the onActivityResult. Thought there might have been a cleaner fix but this gets the job done as well! Thanks